# Woocommerce_new_order hook, using this hook get order customer details in log file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using this function in my php file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'awo_mainmenu' );

function awo_mainmenu($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);error_log("$order",3,'/var/tmp/order.log' );
    var_dump($order);
};
```

In woocommerce, when a new order is placed, this function is to get the order details in order.log file , how can i get the order information (ordered customer billing details) inside my function

Comment: Get Order Info (total, items, etc) from $order Object https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/

Comment: i have done with get order info, but still the order details are not getting in log file.